# Python pandas: Indexing using a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I need to draw a line connecting two points in a dataframe (in the table below, a line connecting S01 to S02, S01 to S04, S03 to S04 etc etc.) Points must not be defined explicitly, but by iterating over the dataframe. The coordinates in each row are that of the 'to' point.

[image: table]

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv(1234.csv')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    x_coords = [df.loc["from", "x"], df.loc["to", "x"]]
    y_coords = [df.loc["from", "y"], df.loc["to", "y"]]
    plt.plot(x_coords, y_coords,'grey', linewidth=0.5)
```

Comment: Post code and data, NOT images of code/data

Answer (score 0):

Jammer worked it out:

```
for i in df.index:
   df.set_index('to')
   a = df.at[i,'From'] #row of from value
   b = a - 1 #correct index value of row
   ax = df.at[b, 'x'] #x value of from
   ay = df.at[b, 'y'] #y of from
   plt.plot([ax,df.at[i,'x']],[ay,df.at[i,'y']],'grey', linewidth=0.5)
```